# Let's not put badge tracking everywhere

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges, user-interface

Well, this is a great feature. Surely users love when they are getting their next badge and which one but whats the reason behind putting it at 3 places?

So we already had this at two places...

[image]

Now why do we need that on the reputation dropdown?

[image]

I don't feel this is useful in anyways as am on this site since 3+ years and I hardly care about my badges. It's surely a neat way to reward the users by giving away badges for the efforts they put by contributing to this site in various ways so we show them badge tracker but lets not do things in such a way that user contribute for the sake of badges and not because they want to contribute.

So putting the same thing at multiple places which hardly adds any convenience is not worth doing.

It's just my opinion.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Can we have an option to disable the new badge privilege section in the achievements dropdown?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/265841)

Comment: [One badge tracker isn’t cool. You know what’s cool? A _billion_ badge trackers](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/)

Comment: But you know, not all users has this "Next tag badge" tracker thingy...

Comment: @Gideon It used to be that one needed 20K to track tag badges; not anymore. You can switch between tracking next privilege and tracking a tag badge.

Comment: @NormalHuman Early on SO, you'll be very excited, specially if it is your 1st time, getting a tag badge. But it becomes annoying (well in case of OP) at some point. I suggest that there should be something like **Dismiss** or **Do not remind me on the future** options there.

Comment: Earning badges is fun, those who are annoyed by earning badges [must just hate fun](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: @TinyGiant: Or we just have collected so many badges that the few that are left are unattainable; my "recommended" next badge is Electorate (1337/600)...

Comment: @MatthieuM. It's still attainable. You left out the second part of the criteria - you're at 16% of your votes going to questions vs the required 25%. So vote on more questions.

Comment: You're right, only 985 votes on questions (provided I abstain myself from voting on answers) and I'll get the badge :D Btw: any chance to change the overlay on the badge progress bar to show 16% / 25% rather than 1337/600...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Screenshot? I'm not sure what overlay you're talking about.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwfdh.png => the excerpt mentions the two conditions necessary, but the one cited shows me as an over-achiever :D

Comment: We've put this experiment on pause for the moment, and may or not relaunch it (thus the status-review tag). But if we do bring this from the dead, we'll be modifying the design so it isn't quite so intrusive. If you have any other design or functionality suggestions for this feature, let us know.

Comment: I've retagged this as [status-completed], since this issue is no longer occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's only a limited amount of activity on this, I'm going to add an answer that says:

> I do not approve of this change.

I've no particular problem with badge tracking on the profile page.  It is pure c**p in my recent achievements drop down (where the two * represent an 'a' and an 'r', and I'm not discussing fish).  Note that it isn't even reporting on recent achievements — it is trying to influence the future.

Also, 'CURRENT COMMUNITY' is as lame as it gets!

Please stop the experiment; please cancel the idea.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to encourage further activity. I am not a huge fan of this idea (even though I implemented the experiment - for science!), but showing recent achievements is something we already have. "Current community" was a concession to the Achievements dialog being otherwise network-wide. Just putting site-specific stuff in there without any preamble would've been even worse. As I mentioned on MSE, this is an experiment. Should it yield positive results (and it's too early to tell at the time I'm writing this), we will spend more time to further polish the tracker.

Comment: Polishing may involve other features (such as picking the next badge to track from the dropdown instead of having to visit the profile), renaming the dropdown from "recent achievements" to just "achievements", and/or something else entirely. We are listening to all feedback during the experiment run and we'll see what makes the most sense on balance (usefulness vs community dislike) when we have enough data to go on.

Comment: thanks for the info. May I respectfully suggest that that is completely the wrong place to put it. If you want to add a new item in the top for 'new badges and stuff you could earn if you are worried about such stuff', then m,aybe. But that drop-down has a purpose and limited space, and getting on for a quarter of the space is pre-empted by this less-than-100%-useful information. If it must be there for some people (I'm not convinced, but I'm only one person, not everyone), then please make it trivial for those of us who have no use for it to remove it.

Comment: I've up-voted the ["please — no" Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265841/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-new-badge-privilege-section-in-the-achiev) on MSE.  But I'm also providing a place for others to agree, or disagree, on MSO.  Not that there's much activity here at the moment, it would seem.  I'm not sure whether that's indifference or something else.

Comment: Putting a pointer over to the profile with a "call to action" sounds like a reasonable thing to test as well. For the moment, let me assure you that we're monitoring how this goes, and we're considering everything we hear. "Failure is always an option" is a motto around here, and we're open to abandoning something that turns out to be a bad idea. Or improving on something that was *mostly* a good idea. :) But first, we watch.

Comment: tbh, I would recommend you to remove it. I got that we decided to add the badge tracker to encourage users for more activity but as one of the most active user on stackoverflow, I've realized that this creates an equal negative impact as well. I dont want users to do activity for the sake of doing it, just to get badges. If I want to give you a best suitable example for this, I would take robo reviewers who blindly review for getting badges. So I dont want users littering around posting questions and answers or voting randomly just to get badges. I hope you get my point.